# jqGrid client side sorting doesn't work when the data is loaded by using method addXMLData

Tags: jqgrid

As title, all data is loaded into the grid instance properly, and the following configuration except the `datatype` works for another grid instance which has live ajax connection to remote data source is applied.

```
datatype: 'local',
gridview: true,
loadonce: true,
viewrecords: true
```

After clicking on any column header to perform sorting, all grid data is lost. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should almost never use the methods like `addXMLData` and `addJSONData`. The methods will be frequently misunderstood. If you have local data you should use `datatype: 'xmlstring'` (or `datatype: 'jsonstring'`) instead and the XML input for the grid provide using the `datastr` parameter.

By the way the value for the `datastr` parameter must be not only `string`. You can use `XMLDOMDocument` or `DOMParser` object for example as the input of the value for `datastr` in case of `datatype: 'xmlstring'`. In case of usage `datatype: 'jsonstring'` it can be an object which represent the JSON data.